# Programmatically Resize Form

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Trying to change the size of a form in AX programmatically.

The commands that seemed most logical doesn't seem to do anything.

```
element.form().design().width(900); 

element.form().design().windowResize(900);

element.resize(900);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me...

To get the form's width/height:

```
element.design().widthValue();

element.design().heightValue();
```

To set it:

```
element.design().height(element.design().heightValue()/2);

element.design().width(element.design().widthValue()/2);
```

Comment: So the extra form() I had in there was messing it up.  Thanks for the quick response.